# jQuery load script executes many times

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have a simple method which loads content and should replace it into an div element:

```
$("a[data-ajax='true']").on('click', function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var goToLink = this.href;
        animateLink(this);
        $('#ajax-target').fadeTo(0.2, 0.5, function () {
            lastLink = currentLink;
            currentLink = goToLink;
            $('#ajax-target').load(goToLink, {}, function () {
                $('body').scrollTop(0);
                $('#ajax-target').fadeTo('slow', 1);
            });
        });
    });
```

Now I load per ajax HTML code which contains the following code:

```
<script>
console.log('Running...')
</script>
```

First time I click on my link which loads the ajax, I see 'Running...' on the console as expected. Second time I do so, 'Running...' is printed twice on the console. Third time this message I get 4 times on the console, and so on. I can't figure out where the problem is. When I load the HTML code per ajax request and replace it per html() method, same problem. Has someone a idea what's wrong?

**Edit**
After the answer here I have now the following code which works:

```
<script>
    var currentLink, lastLink;

    function animateLink(obj) {
        var el = $(obj);
        var animate = el.attr('data-animation');
        if (animate != undefined) {
            animate = animate.toLowerCase();
            animate = animate == 'false' ? false : true;
        } else {
            animate = true;
        }
        if (animate) {
            el.toggle('explode');
        }
    }

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("a[data-ajax='true']").on('click', function (event) {
            event.stopImmediatePropagation();
            event.preventDefault();
            var goToLink = this.href;
            animateLink(this);
            $('#ajax-target').fadeTo(0.2, 0.5, function () {
                lastLink = currentLink;
                currentLink = goToLink;
                $('#ajax-target').load(goToLink, {}, function () {
                    $('body').scrollTop(0);
                    $('#ajax-target').fadeTo('slow', 1);
                });
            });
        });
    });

    function historyBack() {
        $('#ajax-target').fadeTo(0.2, 0.5, function () {
            var newLink = lastLink;
            lastLink = this.href;
            currentLink = newLink;
            $.get(newLink, {}, function (response) {
                $('body').scrollTop(0);
                $('#ajax-target')
                    .html(response)
                    .fadeTo('slow', 1);
            });
        });
    }
</script>
```

This is located on the site directly. This part is not removed when the ajax request is done. The part which is always changed is the following:

```
<div class="content-wrapper" id="ajax-target">
     @Html.Partial("LayoutContentHeader")
     <section class="content">
         @RenderBody()
     </section>
</div>
```

The loaded page is an MVC page, where the main-frame does not contain any HTML or BODY tag, only the content which needs to get replaced and in addition sometimes scripts (how my script above):

```
@if (IsAjax)
{
    if (isMainLayout)
    {

    @Html.Partial("LayoutContentHeader")
    <section class="content">
        @RenderBody()
    </section>
    }
    else
    {
        @RenderBody()
    }



    <script>
        $(function () {
            $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()
        })
    </script>
}
```

As you can see, when we are in a ajax request, I only send the important content.

And the code of a pressed link is for example:

```
<a href="/wilhelmshaven/hse/" data-ajax="true" class="btn btn-block btn-social" style="color: white !important; background-color: rgb(243,156,18)">
     <i class="fa fa-th"></i>HSE
</a>
```

with no link around (which can force bubbling).

Comment: Given those code snippets above, I still need to know how you create and add the `<a>` element, and also need to know `$("a[data-ajax='true']").on('click', function (event)` which headers have this declaration? Are you adding the `a` element dynamically? or one of your partial views has the static HTML?

Comment: Both. First I load the page completely which contains links (of this ajax type). The loaded page contains the same links. I will send you a private message now with the complete code of the initial HTML and the complete code with the ajax loaded stuff. Just a second.

Comment: Ah cant send private message. Was my info enough? I noticed that the stopImmediatePropagation() stops the bubbling of the event. But this can't be a problem, the A tags are not nested.

Comment: This happens when you add `.on()` event targets dynamically or it is also possible that the event declaration is duplicated. People can't replicate your error because your code looks fine and is supposed to work without such behaviour. So I highly suspect that one of your partial view renders the event declaration or something is wrong with your code to add the `a` element. That's why I want to get your code as much as possible to pick up the exact factor.

Comment: As I mentioned ealier, these two factors are most important. _How do you add `a` element_ and _Where and which ways do you declare the click event_ And the redering content is highly suspicious in your `historyback()`, it seems.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this code

```
$("a[data-ajax='true']").on('click', function (event) {

    event.stopImmediatePropagation();

    var goToLink = this.href;
    animateLink(this);
    $('#ajax-target').fadeTo(0.2, 0.5, function () {
        lastLink = currentLink;
        currentLink = goToLink;
        $('#ajax-target').load(goToLink, {}, function () {
            $('body').scrollTop(0);
            $('#ajax-target').fadeTo('slow', 1);
        });
    });
});
```

Reference : http://api.jquery.com/event.stopimmediatepropagation/

Comment: Wow that is crazy. What is behind? Can you describe it for me, I really want to understand it.

Comment: @MichaelBaarz provide me your HTML and scripts as much as you can. Then I will explain why doubling an event happened in your app. And tell me if your web app is SPA, Single Page Application.

Comment: I added all details (hopefully) above. I have to call event.preventDefault() too not to use the normal A way of working. Im very interested in your answer!